# Python 3.4 script keeps calling same function

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to Python and created a script which when called will set my computer to shutdown in x seconds, if called again it will add x seconds to the shutdown.
My problem is that when I check for the arguments the script is called with. If i call the script with '-s' which would shutdown, it first calls the shutdown function and then proceeds to go into the elif statement infinite times until I exit...

```
if arg == '-s':
    shutdown()
elif arg == '-a':
    abort()
else:
    sys.exit("Error: '%s' isn't a valid argument." % arg)
```

The full script is here: http://pastebin.com/VnxANLZ5, as the problem might be else where. Other input for making the script better is welcome aswell.

Comment: While a bit more learning, consider using [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) when using command line arguments.

Comment: will keep that in mind, I don't think that is the reason for the looping function calls though

Comment: How can you tell it's "going into the elif statement infinite times"? What is being printed? Just an unlimited amount of "abort"? Something else?

Comment: As you can see in the pastebin script I inserted a print() when it goes into the if else statement and when I call the script with the '-s' argument it outputs 'shutdown' once then 'abort' until I force the script to exit.

Comment: What is the name of your script?

Comment: its name is shutdown.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your script is named `shutdown.py`, then it's possible that executing `os.system("shutdown -s -t %s" % timeToShutdown)` or `os.system("shutdown -a")` will cause the script to execute itself, rather than invoking Windows' built-in `shutdown` command.

Try renaming your script to something other than `shutdown.py`.

Comment: Yeah that was it, thank you very much! I thought it would be able to distuingish them, since the script has an extension

Comment: On second thought, perhaps you _could_ keep the script's name as-is if you change your `system` calls so they invoke `shutdown.exe` and not just `shutdown`. Then the OS doesn't have to guess whether you mean Python script or executable.

Comment: In the end the name doesn't really matter, I just bound it to my keyboard, I am still surprised it confused them when the script has an extension though, guess it's the same reason I can call the windows shutdown without the .exe extension, and then the file's own directory takes precedence